# Mapping the primary key of the table to the same table in Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, visual-studio-2013

I have one table names SchoolStricture in which the Primary key is "ID" and one another feild is "ParentStructureEntityID" which stores the primary key of the same table. 
The purpose of this table is to create a tree structure. During that parent's id will store in this "ParentStructureEntityID". I am a beginner in NHibernate. 
How can i map these two feild in my .hbm.xml file.

Please help me out of this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml mapping will be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">

  <class name="SchoolStructure" table="SchoolStructure">
    <id name="ID">
      <column name="ID"/>
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="ParentStructure" column="ParentStructureEntityID" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And your class will be:

```
public class SchoolStructure
{
    public virtual int ID {get; private set;}
    public virtual SchoolStructure ParentStructure {  get; set;}
}
```

That's of course for starters. You should ideally override GetHashCode and Equals in proper manner. Finally I humbly suggest using mapping by code instead of xml mapping. Good luck!

Comment: In class should we declare the property "ParentStructureEntityID" or the above mentioned line is enough?

Comment: There is no need for explicit ID columns. If you want you can do it but unless you really need it, I say don't. To sum up, above code is sufficient to make it working.